# Filtering fields containing foreign characters (Chinese) in Access 2010?

Tags: t-sql, special-characters, filtering, ms-access-2010

I have an access 2010 database that contains foreign characters and this data needs to be filtered, searched ect...

The data is stored in a SQL database using NVARCHAR.  Visually they look good but when I go to search on the a field that has these characters I am unable to use the like function. I can get an exact match.

I am able to search for the foreign characters in SQL.

In the front end access 2010 DB that this is attached to when I filter on these columns I am unable to get an exact match or a like match.

It looks lke the sorting function works properly.

How can I get the filtering, sorting ect to function properly in Access 2010?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you are using the query design window in MS Access, the wild card is *, unless you use ALIKE, in which case % will work.

Comment: I tried both * and % and was not successful. both return nothing. I am wondering if it is a setting in access that is not allowing this.

Comment: I wonder is it something to do with the link, because I have just tested with sample foreign characters and an MS Access table, and the filter (filter by form) Like "\*田\*" works.

Comment: I think I have to add a foreign language pack for affice 2010.  I am going to try that and see if it helps.

Comment: I really do not think this will work. You can create a passthrough query like so: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE AName Like N'%田%'` and it will work as expected, even with mixed English / non-English characters (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239530)

Comment: You can also filter the table in MS Access by using `InStrB([AName],"田")>"0"`